# Rotate screen and touch overlay on ViewSonic LD2455 connected to raspberry pi 4b running ubuntu 5.19.0-1015-raspi

Tags: hdmi, ubuntu, touchscreen

I would like to rotate the screen and touch overlay on my ViewSonic TD2455 connected to a Raspberry Pi 4b (4GB) running Ubuntu raspi 22.04 5.19.0-1015-raspi aarch64.

I have tried all the usual suspects without success. I modified `/boot/firmware/config.txt` and added:

```
lcd_rotate=1
```

since I want to rotate both the screen and touch overlay alignment. After that didn't work, I tried using various `xrandr` commands to rotate, but received the following error:

```
$ xrandr -o left
X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request: 140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request: 2 (RRSetScreenConfig)
  Serial number of failed request: 14
  Current serial number in output stream: 14
```

I also installed `arandr` to attempt using the X GUI interface. My monitor shows up as `default` but options for changing the orientation are grayed out except for `normal`.

I next tried the Ubuntu settings app for `Displays`. Changes made here never actually changed the screen orientation and the settings always reverted back to `Landscape`.

Finally, I ran through all of the above again after moving the HDMI cable to the other HDMI output port on the pi4.

I suspect the video driver being loaded is to blame but I'm unsure which driver should be used for my particular touchscreen. BTW, the touchscreen is connected via HDMI and USB-A. It supports usb-c for video, touch, and power but unfortunately, the pi4 does not have the appropriate port.

Would be grateful for any help.